# How can I read data from MongoDB via pure NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to save and read some data from a MongoDB using standard MongoClient and pure NodeJS.
The thing is that I can **write** data but not **read** it.
Here is my code.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
var db;

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, database) {
    if (err !== null) {
        throw err;
    }
    db = database;
});
```

Read function

```
function selectDB(tableName, key, value, callback) {
    var req = {};
    req[key] = value;
    db.collection(tableName).find(req, callback);
}
```

Write function

```
function insertDB(tableName, obj) {
    db.collection(tableName).insertOne(obj, function (err, res) {
        if (err !== null) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
}
```

After I've inserted data into db using this, it can be found using Mongo shell. I use bash `find()` function in the shell successfully but not in the js code.

**Update**

Now I pass the callback to the `toArray()` function as mentioned here, but I still get no result: the callback is not executed.
My `selectDB()`function now looks like this.

```
var req = {};
req[key] = value;
db.collection(tableName).find(req).toArray(callback);
```

**Update**

Here is some data query example:
*Shell*
Input:

`> db.users.find({"email":"aa@aa"})`

Output:

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("572ba1a599f59780f549e5e3"), "email" : "aa@aa", "password" : "2GU9I8syq2Oyf6rSqJNDVyFPOTRwPg3nyQjSwPXppvM=" }`

*JS*

Query (key value pair for the `req` variable):

`key = "email"
value = "aa@aa"`

After that I get the results I described before.

**Update**

After all here is my result handling code (`callback`):

```
//select() here is an alias for selectDB() function declared earlyer
db.select("users", "email", user.email, function (err, cursor) {
        if (cursor === undefined || cursor == null || err !== null) {
            error();
        } else if (cursor.password === user.password) {
            success();
        } else {
            wrong();
        }
    });
```

Finally the callback is executed.
The `error()` function is always executed since cursor in the callback always undefined.

If somebody knows what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it, please answer.

Comment: one way is to implement the binary protocol over the wire... just saying

Comment: @maga, please, take a look on the update.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, please, take a look

Comment: @vp_arth, could you be more specific?

Comment: Where your `selectDB` call code? Where you check results? Is there anything returned into `err` argument of callback?

Comment: @vp_arth, please, see the update abow.

Comment: place `console.error(err)` instead of `error()` and read it for us.

Comment: @vp_arth it's null

Comment: Are you actually mean `selectDB` while write `db.select`?

Comment: @vp_arth , yeap, it's imported as a part of a module with this alias.

Comment: Is there still no results if you change your query to `.findOne({})`?

Comment: @vp_arth, `findOne()` does not work for me since I want to get multiple results.

Comment: Question was `is there any results with findOne/find without query parameters?`

Comment: @vp_arth I checked and the result is the same. May be something is wrong  with connecting to the db?

Comment: But all was ok, while you insert this stuff... It's strange.

Answer (score 2):

What version of the node-mongodb-native (the driver) are you using? In the latest one  [find](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#find) does not accept callback as the second argument.

Comment: Now I did as the new documentation says - passed a callback to the `toArray()` method. Here is the example from the developers `collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
      test.equal(null, err);
      test.equal(3, docs.length);

      db.close();
    });` 
Though the callback is not still executed. Have you got some more ideas?

Comment: @Dmitriy Then it can only be the way you form you `req` query object. Can you provide examples of the document you are trying to reach and the query you are using for it?

Comment: Please, take a look one more time, I've added some sample i/o.

Comment: What does `db.select` do? I don't recall such in the driver. The `req` you have posted is fine, the `db.collection('users').find(req).toArray((err, docs) => { // docs - the resulting array of found docs })` should work with it.